# Symfony2 Querying for a specific amount of objects with order

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to know if it is possible to query only a specific amount of objects and order them. For example I want to query for the newest products added, and I want to get only the newest 10 products from the table.

I dont know if you can order a specific amount in the controller, but I know that you can do `slice` in the twig. However getting the right amount straight from the query would be much more sufficient if possible.

However for some reason I cant even sort the product that I get(http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database). The documentation clearly shows that you can easily order objects. However with my code it does not order:

```
        $newProducts = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->findBy(array(), array('id' => 'DESC'));
```

This returns all of the products. How to query for only 10 of all of them?

How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add more parameters to the `findBy()`-method like:

```
$newProducts = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->findBy(
    array('foo' => 'bar'),
    array('id' => 'ASC'),
    10,
    0
);
```

The [signature of this method](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php):

```
/**
 * Finds entities by a set of criteria.
 *
 * @param array      $criteria
 * @param array|null $orderBy
 * @param int|null   $limit
 * @param int|null   $offset
 *
 * @return array The objects.
 */
public function findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
```

Further reading: [7. Working with Objects / 7.8.2. By Simple Conditions](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)

> The `EntityRepository#findBy()` method additionally accepts **orderings, limit and offset as second to fourth parameters**.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank You!

Comment: @Dominykas55 Glad I could help :)